# Replacing successive decreasing numbers by the last number of the sequence in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I've been trying to solve this problem for quite sometime and I think the logic I'm attempting is flawed.

The objective is to replace a subsequently decreasing sublist of numbers by the last of the sublist.

```
?- compare([1, 3, 7, 6, 5, 10, 9], Result).
Result = [1, 3, 5, 9] ;
false.
```

What I tried was:

```
compare([A,B|T],X):-
       %succ(B,A),
       A is B+1,
       append([],NextX,X),
       compare([B|T],NextX).

remove([A,B|T],X):-
       A=\=B+1,
      compare([B|T],X).
```

I'm not certain how to write the base case for the compare/2 and I think the I'm not correctly converting my logic into the code. What I'm trying here is to compare A and B and drop A from the list if they are successive numbers.
Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. First cover the special case: If the list contains only one element it is in the list.

```
compare([X],[X]).
```

your second rule just needs little altering:

```
compare([A,B|T],X):-       % A is not in the list if
       A is B+1,           % A = B+1
       compare([B|T],X).   % Note: X is the same as in head of rule
```

Your predicate remove/2 is should be the 3rd rule of compare/2 covering the alternative case:

```
compare([A,B|T],[A|X]):-   % A is in the list
      A=\=B+1,             % if A is not B+1
      compare([B|T],X).
```

Now the query works:

```
   ?-  compare([1, 3, 7, 6, 5, 10, 9], Result).
Result = [1,3,5,9] ? 
yes
```

However, this predicate only works if the first list is variable free. You can't use it the other way round:

```
   ?- compare([A,B,C], [1,2]).
     ERROR at  clause 2 of user:compare/2 !!
     INSTANTIATION ERROR- X is A+B: expected bound value
```

If you use library(clpfd) on the other hand ...

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

compare([X],[X]).
compare([A,B|T],X):-
       A #= B+1,
       compare([B|T],X).
compare([A,B|T],[A|X]):-
       A #\= B+1,
       compare([B|T],X).
```

... the above query works too:

```
   ?- compare([A,B,C], [1,2]).
A = C = 2,
B = 1 ? ;
A = 1,
B = 3,
C = 2 ? ;
no
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. I'm very much new to Prolog. Haven't worked with modules so far. Should have a look at the second option. Thanks